# Do Jenkins and SonarQube need to be on the same machine?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am trying to run a SonarQube scan from Jenkins job. I have the SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins plugin installed v2.6.1 running on local Jenkins (for dev only);

I have seen conflicting reports on whether or not you *can* run SonarQube on a different server then Jenkins. It wouldn't make sense if you *could not* do that... if you can, instructions on how to accomplish it would be great. Simply putting in the URL to the SQ server where Jenkins expects a directory to Sonar Runner locally, does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jenkins and SonarQube do not have to be on the same machine.

The SonarQube plugin in Jenkins will run one of these three scanners:

- SonarQube Scanner
- SonarQube Scanner for Maven
- SonarQube Scanner for MsBuild

Depending on which scanner you use, it works a bit differently:

- For the SonarQube Scanner, pass `-Dsonar.host.url=http://your.host:1234` as additional arguments. (or add it to your `sonar.properties` file)
- For the SonarQube Scanner for Maven, add `-Dsonar.host.url=http://your.host:1234` to *your maven build step*.
- For the SonarQube Scanner for MsBuild, add `/d:sonar.host.url=http://your.host:1234` to your `MsBuild.exe` call.